# how to generate columns dynamically based on today date in edit table asp .net

Tags: asp.net

I have a database table that has 365 days as fields (columns.)
For ex: D01012016, 02012016 etc  (ddmmyyyy)

In the aspx page I want to show only 30 fields starting from todays date.
For ex: if todays date is 10072016, the show only
D1007216,D11072016, D12072016 .. upto D30072016

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this sql query.

```
declare @Counter int,@SQL varchar(max),@ColumnName varchar(9)
set @Counter=0
set @SQL='select '

while(@Counter<30) 
begin
    select @ColumnName= REPLACE(convert(varchar,DATEADD(DD,@Counter,getdate()),103), '/', '')
    set @SQL=@SQL+'D'+ @ColumnName+ (case when @Counter !=29 then ',' else '' end)
    set @Counter=@Counter+1
end

set @SQL=@SQL+' from TableName'

exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: super. thanks yatin. how can I use this query in an aspx page and show these columns? If you can advise it will be great.

Comment: On Button click you have to that data using store procedure and bind that data to gridview or any other control that you want.